# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My Project has employee table and it has (name, address ... , NIC) 
Here **NIC** has pattern 9 numbers and V (Ex: 917200424V) and i have add varchar(100) type for that,

And this NIC value is going to login table and it has (passowrd, tbl_employee_NIC)
Employee table **NIC** value is passing to this **tbl_employee_NIC**.

Bellow is the code for login :

```
<?php

require_once '../../config/config.php';

$tbl_employee_NIC = $_POST['tbl_employee_NIC'];
$passwordI = $_POST['password'];
$passwordI = md5($passwordI);


    try {
        $sql = "SELECT e.NIC, e.status, e.employeeBranch, e.employeeRole,
                       l.status,l.tbl_employee_NIC, l.password 
                FROM tbl_employee e, tbl_login l 
                WHERE l.tbl_employee_NIC=:tbl_employee_NIC 
                  AND l.tbl_employee_NIC=e.NIC 
                  AND e.status='Active'";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':tbl_employee_NIC' => $tbl_employee_NIC));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        if (count($result)) {
            $row = $result[0];
            $dbPassword = $row[6];

            if ($passwordI == $dbPassword) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row[0];
                $_SESSION['Branch'] = $row[2];
                $_SESSION['Role'] = $row[3];


                //update active in login
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tbl_login` 
                                        SET `status`='Active' 
                                        WHERE tbl_employee_NIC=".$_SESSION['username']);
                 $stmt->execute();
                // ./update active in login

               $_SESSION['SUCCESS'][] = "Welcome! ".$_SESSION['username'];
                header("Location: " . '../login/home.php');

               } else {
                header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                $_SESSION['ERROR'][] = "User Name or Password is wrong..!";
            }
        } else {

            header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

            $_SESSION['ERROR'][] = "You have trun over the company .. SORRY!";
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {

        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

        $_SESSION['ERROR'][] = $ex->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

But it gives an error when i am going to  enter , Here it is :

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '917200500V' in 'where clause'

Firstly i thought the error is from code then i just update one row without "V" in **NIC** of employee table  and  **tbl_employee_NIC** of login tavle. But it has successfully logged in. so could anyone give the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is probably in this statement.

As `tbl_employee_NIC` is a string column the data must be wrapped in quotes. So amend the query like this

```
//update active in login
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tbl_login` 
                        SET `status`='Active' 
                        WHERE tbl_employee_NIC='{$_SESSION['username']}'");
```

Or if you prefer

```
//update active in login
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tbl_login` 
                        SET `status`='Active' 
                        WHERE tbl_employee_NIC='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Comment: I had a backtick at the end of the first SQL statement instead of a single quote. **which I have now fixed!** Either that or @PhiterFernandes thinks I downvoted him and the downvote was retaliation.